How to add groups fieldset with add row in admin block in magento 2
I need to add groups fieldset or bundle fieldset with "Add Row" section.
like -

    $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
    $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('custom_');
    $customerId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry(
        RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID
    );
    $storeid = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'base_fieldset',
        ['legend' => __('Details')]
    );

    $fieldset->addField(
        'percentage',
        'text',
        [
            'name' => 'percentage',
            'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
            'label' => __('Percentage'),
            'title' => __('Percentage'),
            'class' => 'validate-number validate-digits-range digits-range-0-100',
            'value' => $rowcom,
        ]
    );


Do you want to add in system configuration ?

No, I want custom form.

Please add the following fieldset to your UI form. After that, you will be able to display dynamic rows.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer_percentage_configuration">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Percentage Configuration</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="dynamic_row">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/dynamic-rows/templates/default</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">dynamicRows</item>
                    <item name="recordTemplate" xsi:type="string">record</item>
                    <item name="deleteButtonLabel" xsi:type="string">Remove</item>
                    <item name="addButtonLabel" xsi:type="string">Add New </item>
                    <item name="deleteProperty" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dndConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <container name="record">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Record label goes here</item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record</item>
                        <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="showFallbackReset" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <field name="sub_id">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sub_id</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">sub_id</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                            <item name="disabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
                
                <field name="country_id">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</item>
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Country</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">country_id</item>
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/country</item>
                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
                <field name="percentage">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Percentage</item>
                            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">percentage</item>
                            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">percentage</item>
                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </field>
                <actionDelete>
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>
                            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                            <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Actions</item>
                            <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">data-grid-actions-cell</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </actionDelete>
            </container>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>

As a result you can see the below fieldset:


can use block php?

@RubelParvaz, you can check Create product dynamic row attribute
